# How to add all objects to Global search in Lightning?

Tags: community, lightning, customization, global-search

I have give `Allow search` Field True for all the objects what i want and pined them in the search layout also to do search in all the objects, what i have did you can see in the below screen short.

**Note:** This all Done in Classic View
[image]

But when i have searched in Lightning mode, i am getting **No Data found** for all those objects, expect for some objects.

I have seen one more problem here while seaeching data in classic view(**for Eg:** if i search any record name like **Test Record** it is not searching in all the objects, after clicking on `Search All` it's showing the data.)for this secinaro you can see the screen short below.
[image]

one more thing in lightning it is searching for the following: as shown in the below screen short, and Not for Records which are present in the objects.
[image]

Can any one help me on this to achive it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global search has many limitations, especially in lightning. What we usually end-up doing in orgs where we need to search on records for multiple objects is use ISV partner apps which are available on the AppExchange. In the [Salesforce Summer '17 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_search_federated_search.htm) you can see that Salesforce has partnered up with Coveo, Docurated, and Swiftype.

Each provide search solutions, however, from what I have tested and know (since I am an employee there) is that Coveo offers an OOTB free solution where you can leverage Salesforce's index with SOSL and SOQL to display object records.

the listing is available [here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009x8GjEAI) and the getting started guide is [here](https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SalesforceV2/Getting+Started+with+Coveo+for+Salesforce+Express).

To give you an idea of the end result after the initial configuration:

[image]

and you can customize what objects/records you want to display through an interface editor. Works in lightning and classic.

for further options you can read the following posts from the admin and developer blogs:

- [More Search Options for Your Org](https://admin.salesforce.com/simplify-searching-federated-search)
- [Federated Search for Salesforce ISVs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2017/08/federated-search-for-salesforce-isvs.html)